# Theorem 7.32 in Apostol's MATHEMATICAL ANALYSIS, 2nd ed: How to establish differentiability?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Here is Theorem 7.32 in the book *Mathematical Analysis - A Modern Approach to Advanced Calculus* by Tom M. Apostol, 2nd edition:

> Let $\alpha$ be of bounded variation on $[a, b]$ and assume that $f \in R(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$. Define $F$ by the equation
> $$
> F(x) = \int_a^x f \, d \alpha, \qquad \mbox{ if } x \in [a, b]. 
> $$
> Then we have:

> i) $F$ is of bounded variation on $[a, b]$.

> ii) Every point of continuity of $\alpha$ is also a point of continuity of $F$.

> iii) If $\alpha \nearrow$ on $[a, b]$, the derivative $F^\prime(x)$ exists at each point $x$ in  $(a, b)$ where $\alpha^\prime(x)$ exists and where $f$ is continuous. For such $x$, we have
> $$
> F^\prime(x) = f(x) \alpha^\prime(x). 
> $$

And, here is Apostol's proof of this theorem.

> If suffices to assume that $\alpha \nearrow$ on $[a, b]$. If $x \neq y$, Theorem 7.30 implies that
> $$
> F(y) - F(x) = \int_x^y f \, d \alpha = c \big[ \alpha(y) - \alpha(x) \big],
> $$
> where $m \leq c \leq M$ (in the notation of Theorem 7.30). Statements (i) and (ii) follow at once from this equation. To prove (iii), we divide by $y-x$ and observe that $c \to f(x)$ as $y \to x$.

Finally, here is Theorem 7.30 (First Mean-Value Theorem for Riemann-Stieltjes Integrals):

> Assume that $\alpha \nearrow$ and let $f \in R(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$. Let $M$ and $m$ denote, respectively, the $\sup$ and $\inf$ of the set $\big\{ f(x) \colon x \in [a, b] \big\}$. Then there exists a real number $c$ satisfying $m \leq c \leq M$ such that
> $$
> \int_a^b f(x) \, d \alpha(x) = c \int_a^b d \alpha(x) = c \big[ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \big].
> $$
> In particular, if $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, then $c = f \left( x_0 \right)$ for some $x_0$ in $[a, b]$.

Now my question is, although how (i) and (ii) follow is clear, how to gaurantee that $c \to f(x)$ as $y \to x$? After all, the only thing we know about $c$ from Theorem 7.30 in that $m \leq c \leq M$.

However, we can apply Theorem 7.30 to the interval with endpoints $x$ and $y$ and thus conclude that  $c$ depends on $x$ and $y$ so that we then have
$$
F(y) - F(x) = \int_x^y f \, d\alpha = c_{x, y} \big[ \alpha(y) - \alpha(x) \big]. 
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $m = \inf \{ f(x) : x \in [a,b] \}$ and $M = \sup \{ f(x) : x \in [a,b] \}$, and $f$ is continuous, what would you conclude about $c$ as $y \to x$?  Can you see why it is unnecessary to specify that $c$ is some function of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: the only thing we can say that if $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, then the $m$ and $M$ not only are real numbers but also are actually in the range (i.e. the image set) of $f$. I'm afraid I'm not sure how we can deduce from this that $c \to f(x)$ as $y \to x$.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood In Theorem 7.32, the role of $y$ and $x$ is equivalent to the role of $b$ and $a$ in Theorem 7.30.  So as $y \to x$ in 7.32, the interval on which the infimum and supremum of $f$ is considered becomes the singleton $\{x\}$.  Since $f$ is continuous, this implies that $m \to x$ and $M \to x$, thus $c \to f(x)$.